# How do I show that a Desktop environment is NOT installed?

Tags: centos

I need to document that a server is running a minimal installation of CentOS.  I'm aware that I can `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION` (returns blank), but is there a better way of showing that the OS is minimal install?

Comment: Have whomever has physical access to the server plug a VGA cord and monitor into it and they'll learn quickly it is a minimal installation :)

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "minimal" install. IIRC there's a package list on the DVD that specifies which packages are in the "minimal" install profile, you could `rpm -qa` for stuff that's outside of that list but that sounds time consuming. If you're just trying to make sure a desktop isn't installed you can do a `rpm -qa | egrep -i (gnome|kde|x11)`